# borel measurable and measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,A,\mu)$ be a measure space, $f:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$$\to$$(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ be a nonnegative measurable function and define the graph
$G(f)=\{(\omega,y)\in\Omega\times\mathbb{R} : 0<y<f(\omega)\}$. Consider the function $\Phi : (\Omega \times \mathbb{R} ,\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}) \to (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R},\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B})$ defined by  $\Phi(\omega,y)=f((\omega),y)$ and $\Psi :(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} , \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B}) \to ( \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}$) defined by
$\Psi (x,y)=x-y$.

How can we show that a) $\Phi$  is measurable and b) $\Psi$ is Borel measurable? I know that for part (a) I have to show that $\phi ^{-1}$ (A$\times$ B) is measurable for $A\in \mathcal{A}$, $B\in \mathcal{B}$ but I do not know how. And for (b), I have no idea!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean $\Phi(\omega,y)=(f(\omega),y)$.

Hint: for part (a), check first on rectangular sets, i.e. write down 
$$\Phi^{-1}(A\times B)=\{(\omega,y):f(\omega)\in A, y\in B\}$$
and use the measurability of $f$...

For part (b), is $\Psi$ continuous? What is the relation between continuous functions and Borel measurable functions?

Comment: for part a you mean if f is measurable then $$\Phi^{-1}(A\times B)=\{(\omega,y):f(\omega)\in A, y\in B\}$$ is also measurable? Idonot understand :( could u plz more explain this?

Comment: You need to check $\Phi^{-1}(A\times B)$ is a measurable set if $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets. Note that this holds since $\{y:y\in B\}=B$ is measurable (since we required $B$ is measurable set), and $\{\omega:f(\omega)\in A\}=f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable since $f$ is by hypothesis measurable function and we required $A$ to be measurable set.